# What are valid formats for numbers in XML

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

I'm developing a WCF web service that is being called by an SAP installation and am running into problems related to their serialization of negative numbers.  They're passing values like "123.45-" rather than "-123.45", which is causing the deserialization to choke.  I think I can get around it by defining everything as a string in the XML and then manually looking for trailing signs.

My question is is this even a valid XML number representation?  I found [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double), that seems to indicate that the sign (if present) must precede the number.  At the end of the day, I'll have to add whatever it takes to deal with what they send.  I guess it's just ego wanting to know that this is in fact wrong from a spec standpoint ;)

Comment: XML itself doesn't define any specific representation for numeric values. XML Schema is something additional to describe a set of possible valid XML documents (XML Schema may or may not be used by your SAP installation - I'd guess no).

Comment: Why use a standard representation when it's so fun to make up your own :-) . Here's XML Schema for float http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#float . I'd ask the integration partner about it because surely others have had to find the work around.

Comment: @GregHewgill - got it.  I assumed the XML Schema was **the** definition of valid XML.

Comment: @DavidW - at this point, I've been told that they're not changing.  I guess I was really wanting to know whether I should be annoyed at them for using a non-standard representation (which they are) or at MicroSoft for not being able to deserialize a valid number format.  At least if it was MS's fault, I might be able to get something done about it.  (OK, so that's not likely.)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid number representation in the strict sense of the **XML schema**. If you're talking about a SOAP endpoint, you can browse to the service WSDL file, then follow the links to the schema expected in the request and responses - WCF will usually use xs:int, xs:decimal, xs:double, etc. to represent number types.

What to do next depends on how much you can influence the client to send "valid" numbers for you. If you can't, and you must support the existing requests, then it becomes "valid" for your scenario, and you'll need to somehow deal with those. Maybe not an ideal world, but sometimes interop causes those kinds of issues.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos.  I suspected as much.  At this point, I've essentially been told "Make it work".  I did just get a workaround (call it a string and manually parse) in place for one field.  Now to go through and add this to the other 20 or so numeric fields.

Comment: Saxon has an XSD extension that allows you to convert input fields before validation, using XPath expressions (it.s called saxon:preprocess). It's probably too non-standard to be a reasonable solution. However, filtering the data before validation, e.g. using a SAX filter, might well be workable.